# Tkinter gui calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Hey i want to make it so on my calculator when a button is pressed the number of the button clicked is entered on screen. Would anyone have an idea of doing this in the most efficient way possible?. 
Here is my code so far.

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("150x170")

lbl1 = tkinter.Label(text = "Calculator").grid(row = 1, column = 4)

displaynum = 0
lb = tkinter.Label(text = displaynum, borderwidth = 4).grid(row = 2, column = 4)
def displayednum():
    global displaynum
    lbl = tkinter.Label(text = displaynum, borderwidth = 4).grid(row = 2, column = 4)

for n in range(1,4):
    btn1 = tkinter.Button(text = n,borderwidth = 2, command = changenumber ).grid(row = 3,column = n*2)
    lbl2 = tkinter.Label(text = " ").grid(row = 3, column = n*2+1)
for u in range(1,4):
    btn2 = tkinter.Button(text = u+3,borderwidth = 2).grid(row = 6, column = u*2)
    lbl3 = tkinter.Label(text = " ").grid(row = 6, column = u*2+1)
for m in range(1,4):
    btn2 = tkinter.Button(text = m+6,borderwidth = 2).grid(row = 9, column = m*2)
    lbl4 = tkinter.Label(text = " ").grid(row = 9, column = m*2+1)


window.mainloop()
```

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: To start with: When creating a button, provide a `command` argument pointing to a function that updates the number display.

Answer (score 0):

The function to change the label text could be implemented like this:

```
def changenumber(label, val):
    label.config(text=str(val))
```

However you should be careful while assigning variables.
Both variables lbl1 and lb are None.
You should try it this way:

```
lbl1 = tkinter.Label(text = "Calculator")
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
lb = tkinter.Label(text = displaynum, borderwidth = 4)
lb.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
```